# Not able to connect Google Cloud MySQL Instance from App Engine Node JS standard environment

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Not able to connect MySQL Google Cloud Instance Database from NodeJS/Express App Engine.

Able to connect Database locally as I have added my local machine IP in "Authorized networks" of SQL Instance Settings.

Tried using below code in NodeJS App Engine Instance but facing error not able to connect db.

```
{
    "username": "abcd",
    "password": "abcd123",
    "database": "dummy",
    "host": "localhost",
    "socketPath": "/cloudsql/{project-name}:{instance-zone}:{instance-name}",
    "post": 3306,
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "dialectOptions": {
          "socketPath": "/cloudsql/{project-name}:{instance-zone}:{instance-name}"
    }
  }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you followed the guides on Setting up a Cloud SQL instance, Configuring App Engine and Connecting to Cloud SQL at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard?

Comment: You have not added any messages or logs that can help us to help you. Please add more details.

Comment: Issue resolved. I was trying to connect MySQL instance from different project in GCP. I moved MySQL instance in Same Project where NodeJS backend hosted in App Engine. Now its working

Comment: You modified the question to be the solution. Instead revert back to the question and post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having the Cloud SQL MySQL Instance on a different project as the GAE app caused trhe issue.

Just moving the isntance solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you need vpc_access_connector in app.yaml.

or you can follow sample code from gcp app engine nodejs
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/cloudsql